# Microsoft Access z-index property

Tags: ms-access, z-index, send, back

I have a form including listboxes. I'm trying to change order of listboxes. I tried bring front or send back but they are not working in form view. I found z index property for arranging their priority. However, following codes are not working. Is this correct way to do it? Or is there any other way with or without codes to do this?

```
Me.Controls.SetChildIndex (Me.List0 , Me.List1)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does the error message says ? Are you on VBA with Access ?

Comment: It says syntax error and yes I'm on VBA but I'm not ever sure if these codes are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Without using code:
You can change the z-order by right-clicking any control and selecting "Position" then selecting either "Bring to Front" or "Send to Back."

Unfortunately, Access does *not* support the `ZOrder` method for manipulation using code. Microsoft Forms *does* support the `ZOrder` method which can get confusing when it comes up on Access Help.

As I reread your question, I wonder if you're talking about *tab* order. If so, right-click and bring up "Properties," select the "Other" tab, then adjust the "Tab Index" property. Also, make sure that the "Tab Stop" property immediately beneath is set to "Yes." In code you would use `FormName.ControlName.TabIndex=0` to set a control to the first tab position.

Hope this helps!

Reference: Personal experience (and hours of frustration)

Answer (score 1):

```
docmd.RunCommand acCmdDesignView

forms("form1").Controls("text0").inselection=true

docmd.runcommand acCmdSendToBack '(or docmd.runcommand acCmdBringToFront)

docmd.RunCommand acCmdFormView
```

Also, ZOrder is still not supported by Access 2016. As such, I have not yet learned a way to write a single line of code that puts a control in between two others, I just send the middle to back and then the back to back, and expand this to however many controls have to overlap.

And last, even though you use the VBA for `ZOrder`, your English does ambiguously sound like `forms("form1").Controls("text0").TabIndex=34`, which as Olek suggested, is also quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

I did this on one Access form: The control I wanted on top I just cut and pasted it back to the form, then moved it over the one I wanted to cover.  In this case, it was a text box (bound), almost the same size as a combo box (unbound); only the dropdown of the combo extended a bit to the right of the text box, so when the form was loaded the text box looked like a combo box.  The user clicked the dropdown and made a choice and the record(s) pulled up were reflected in the text box.