# User forms VBA position - bringing forward and backward

Tags: forms, vba, position

Is there any index to control which picture, textbox, frame... will be in front of the other? Is there any property similar tor the PHP's z-index?

I am trying to right click and sending backward, but I get no change.

Answer (score 2):

In response to this old question of moving items to the front or rear on Excel forms, I have found that the "Bring Forward" and "Send Backward" controls do not work.  By accident I found that if you delete an item in an Excel form and then undelete it, it will move it to the front.

Comment: Yes. This is true. Tested for labels of vba Excel userform.

Answer (score 1):

After a fair bit of searching, it would seem the answer to your question is No.  There doesn't appear to be any way to adjust the Zorder or use "Bring to Front" or "Send to Back" in VBA.  As per the answer here:

[Use Z-order and position to organize open forms in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202271/use-z-order-and-position-to-organize-open-forms-in-ms-access)

And here:

[Microsoft Access z-index property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517419/microsoft-access-z-index-property)

The only alternative I have found mentioned was to layer your controls perfectly and the use `.Setfocus` to bring them to the front.  Personally in my database I simply just toggle `.Visible` for the control to `False` or `True` in order to give the illusion of controls "Moving".

**Note:** After reviewing your tags I notice you don't have an Excel or Access one in there.  My answer is based off of Access, if you are using excel please adjust your tags.